# OWSP Java Encoder: prevent specific attributes from being escaped

Tags: java, clojure, owasp

I'm cleaning the third-party HTML content using the [Clojure's wrapper](https://github.com/alxlit/autoclave) on OWSP Java Encoder library. I've prepared a policy that keeps `src` attribute on `iframe` elements if it matches some regex templates, e.g. YouTube or Vkontakte embedded iframes.

However, the final `src` value is escaped so the URL doesn't work. Here is an example. The source HTML:

```
<iframe src='https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-30493961&id=456241043&hash=a3148de1cd04c77b' width='640' height='360' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the result:

```
<iframe src="https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid&#61;-30493961&amp;id&#61;456241043&amp;hash&#61;a3148de1cd04c77b"></iframe>
```

I didn't manage to find any docs on how to prevent the returned `src` value from being escaped. How can I do that?

PS my source code:

```
;; policy declaration
(html-policy
   :allow-elements ["iframe"] ;; a long vector here with other tags

   :allow-attributes
   ["src"
    :matching [#"(?i)\Qhttps://vk.com/video_ext.php\E.+"]
    :on-elements ["iframe"]]

   :allow-standard-url-protocols)

;; sanitation
(html-sanitize policy html-string)
```

Comment: According to the source code (https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/78f5461c0a336f65178c8c0d8f4b9e3de870859f/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/HtmlStreamRenderer.java#L196), attribute values are encoded unconditionally.

Comment: Right, I've found that artefact already. It seems there is no a change to override this.